# How to bind data from controller to ng-repeat - textbox using index number

Tags: angularjs

I have two select drop down list and one text box.

There is option to clone each row using ng-repeat.

When selecting dropdown value i will get value from database. So i need to bind that value in textbox.

Controller:

```
 $scope.major_change = function(value, index){
  $scope.major_id = value;
};

$scope.minor_change = function(value, index){
  $scope.minor_id = value;
  $scope.active = 'active';
  var temp = surveyService.getDistList($scope.major_id, $scope.minor_id);
  temp.then(function (msg) {
      alert(msg.data[0].gi_code);
      $scope.gi_code[index] = msg.data[0].gi_code;
          }, function () {
              $scope.Error = 'Error in adding record';
          });

};
```

[Html Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zF5Y.png)

Comment: put your HTML Code also which you have tried.

Comment: provide a pluker plz!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/vXYr0zqM8TML65MqqUdR?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding the wrong value to `ng-model`. This was the reason two way binding was not working.

```
$scope.minor_change = function(value, index){

  $scope.minor_id = value;
  /*$scope.dist.gi_code[index] = value;*/
  $scope.dist_list[index].gi_code=value;
}
```

**Working Plunke**r: https://plnkr.co/edit/dRr90YtjtSRhHUZKisMQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what actually your html code look like but may be this help you as desired.You can use two-way data binding as :

HTML Code :

```
<tr>
<td><select class="select1"></option></option></td>
<td><select class="select1"></option></option></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="value" ></td>
```

Javascript Code :

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.value= $('.select1').val();    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.. but i am not expecting this one.. Could you please look into this plukr - https://plnkr.co/edit/vXYr0zqM8TML65MqqUdR?p=preview